# Помогите с кодом из книги

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

```
const hummus = function(factor) {  const ingredient = function(amount, unit, name) { let ingredientAmount amount * factor; if (ingredientAmount > 1) { unit += "s"; } console.log('${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}'); }; ingredient(l, "банка", "нута"); ingredient(0.25, "стакан", "кунжутной пасты"); ingredient(0.25, "стакан", "лимонного сока"); ingredient(l, "зубок", "чеснока"); ingredient(2, "столовые ложки", "оливкового масла"); ingredient(0.5, "чайной ложки", "кумина"); };
```

Здравствуйте! Изучаю книгу выразительный JavaScript в большинстве случаев, там код не разбирается по полкам, подскажите что делает этот код:

```
console.log('${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}'); };
```

Comment: Конкретно этот код выводит строку `${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}` в консоль. Как есть. Не более того

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно этот код выводит строку `${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}` в консоль. Как есть. Не более того.

Но, возможно, в книге опечатка или неправильно отсканирована и воспроизведена и имелось в виду это:

```
console.log(`${ingredientAmount} ${unit} ${name}`);
```

То есть данные, заключённые **не в одинарные** кавычки, а в **обратные**.

А это есть вывод **[шаблонной строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)**, где можно использовать выражения внутри. И где вместо `${test}` подставится значение переменной `test` в строку

```
let a = 5;
let b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and not ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

выведет в консоль: `Fifteen is 15 and not 20.`

Comment: Давно Вас не было :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Часто это слышу :D  .....Пока я добрый))